# The numerical value of this determinant is?

Tags: matrices, logarithms, determinant

For positive numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$, the numerical value of the determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
1   & \log_xy &  \log_xz \\
\log_yx & 1  & \log_yz \\
\log_zx & \log_zy & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}

is

(A) $0$

(B) $\log \ xyz$

(C) $\log \ (x+y+z)$

(D) $\log \ x \ \log \ y \ \log \ z$

My solution:

I changed the bases of the elements. I wrote $\log_yx$ as $\frac{\log x}{\log y}$. I did the same for the others. Then, I took $\log x$, $\log y$ and $\log z$ common from columns one, two and three respectively. I then multiplied $\log x$, $\log y$ and $\log z$ to rows one, two and three respectively. I got the following determinant:

\begin{vmatrix}
\log x   & 1 &  1 \\
1 & \log y  & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \log z \\
\end{vmatrix}

I used cofactor expansion to get the value of the determinant as
$\log \ x \ \log \ y \ \log \ z  -  \log \ xyz  +  2$

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct solution?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Multiply **first** the first row with $\log x$, the second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the first, second and third rows by $\log{x}$, $\log{y}$ and $\log{z}$ respectively gives
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\log{x}   & \log{y} &  \log{z} \\
\log{x}   & \log{y} &  \log{z} \\
\log{x}   & \log{y} &  \log{z} \\
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
If you calculate the determinant normally you get
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1   & \log_xy &  \log_xz \\
\log_yx & 1  & \log_yz \\
\log_zx & \log_zy & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=1+\log_y{x}\log_z{y}\log_x{z}+\log_z{x}\log_x{y}\log_y{z}-\log_x{z}\log_z{x}-\log_y{z}\log_z{y}-\log_x{y}\log_y{x}$$
$$=1+\frac{\ln{x}\ln{y}\ln{z}}{\ln{y}\ln{z}\ln{x}}+\frac{\ln{x}\ln{y}\ln{z}}{\ln{z}\ln{x}\ln{y}}-\frac{\ln{z}\ln{x}}{\ln{x}\ln{z}}-\frac{\ln{z}\ln{y}}{\ln{y}\ln{z}}-\frac{\ln{y}\ln{x}}{\ln{x}\ln{y}}$$
$$=1+1+1-1-1-1=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me follow your thought:

Taking $\log x, \log y, \log z$ out of the columns.

$$\log x \log y \log z \begin{vmatrix} \frac1{\log x} & \frac1{\log x} & \frac1{\log x} \\ \frac1{\log y} & \frac1{\log y} & \frac1{\log y} \\ \frac1{\log z} & \frac1{\log z} & \frac1{\log z}  \end{vmatrix}$$

You then multiply $\log x, \log y, \log z$ to the rows. This would give you the determinant of the  all ones matrix, hence the determinant is $0$.